# Js ReGex non-capturing group not working

Tags: javascript, regex

my problem is, i need to capture an script src, but i need to get it only if it has an script tag before the src.

So here follow my regex and the options i tried

```
String: <script src="http://example.net"></script>
Regex: /(?:\<script[^]+src=("|'))([^]+)(?="|')/g
Match: <script src="http://example.net
```

Second option:

```
String: <script src="http://example.net"></script>
Regex: /(?!\<script[^]+src=("|'))([^]+)(?="|')/g
Match: script src="http://example.net
```

What i need to get is: http://example.net

I really do appreciate any help.

This is the tool i'm using for testing: http://www.regexr.com/

Thanks,

Comment: What the heck is `[^]` supposed to match in a regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expression is not the right tool for parsing HTML, but to fix the problem you can use the [`exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) method in a loop to grab all your submatches and then push the match results of the captured group into an array.

```
var s = '<script src="http://foo.net"></script><script src="http://bar.com"></script>';

var re  = /<script[^>]+?src=['"]([^'"]+)['"]/g, 
matches = [];

while (m = re.exec(s)) {
  matches.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(matches) //=> [ 'http://foo.net', 'http://bar.com' ]
```

Comment: thx, that worked with my regex, i'll try to do it by the regex to save performance but i'll use that for now, thx

Answer (score 0):

This syntax `[^]+` as far i know, works only with old versions of internet explorer *(but perhaps with newer versions too, you know microsoft)* and means *all that is not nothing (i.e. everything), one or several times*.

If you want to match all the characters until the end of the tag and before the attribute you want, you need to use `[^>]+?` (as you can see) with a lazy quantifier.

For the second ugly `[^]`, since it is between quotes, you only need to replace it with `[^"']` that excludes quotes.

The result you need is not the whole match but the content of the capture group.

```
<script[^>]+?src=["']([^"']+)["']
```

Comment: i've tested on chrome, ff, safari and ie10, and it works, but still i can't exclude the first group from the match

Comment: What do you mean you can't exclude the first group?  I still don't understand what you're trying to do here..

Comment: The i think you didn't understood the question, i want to ignore the first group from the match

Comment: i'm trying to get everithynt that is inside the src="", but it has to be inside the script tag, because i receive a huge string with a lot of html img tags with the src.

Comment: @Sakai: You can't since Javascript doesn't have the lookbehind feature. you need to use capture group to "ignore" the content before.

Comment: The first element of the match array is always the whole string that matched, but the *second* element of the match array (`m[1]`) will be only what matches the part in parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to do or where you got that syntax.

If you want values of the `src` attribute in all `script` tags, why not just search for `/<script[^>]*\ssrc="([^"]*)"/` and examine the first subexpression match..

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start for you:

```
/<script src=\"(.*)(?=\")/g
```

Retrieve the value of the first capturing group returned by this expression.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the regexr.com result:

```
String: <script src="http://example.net"></script>
Regex: /(?:<script src=")([^"]+)/g
group#1: http://example.net
```

And here is the example javascript code:

```
s = '<script src="http://example.net"></script>';
url = s.split(/(?:<script src=")([^"]+)/g)[1];
```

Since javascript doesn't support lookbehind assertions, - AFAIK - You can't both match only the url and check if there is a script tag before the url. Therefore, As an alternative of lookbehind assertions, this is the fastest and easiest solution that i know.